# In Angular compare two different objects and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, angular, object, filter, object-comparison

In Angular I have this 2 arrays with objects.

1. Main Object

   [
   {
   "userId": 8,
   "name": "Adfgh",
   "uniqueId": "rthj",
   "source": {
   "key": "0",
   "mode": "d",
   "name": "tev5"
   },
   "headers": [
   {
   "content": "b",
   "id": "01"
   },
   {
   "content": "m",
   "id": "04"
   },
   {
   "content": "R1",
   "id": "02"
   },
   {
   "content": "083083",
   "id": "03"
   },
   {
   "content": "5",
   "id": "05"
   }
   ],
   "key": "IPP Master Key",
   "destination": "5"
   },
   {
   "userId": 8,
   "name": "FGHJKNJKN",
   "uniqueId": "etjhjub",
   "source": {
   "key": "M0",
   "mode": "C",
   "name": "DEVm6"
   },
   "headers": [
   {
   "content": "n",
   "id": "01"
   },
   {
   "content": "m",
   "id": "04"
   },
   {
   "content": "R1",
   "id": "02"
   },
   {
   "content": "083083",
   "id": "03"
   },
   {
   "content": "6",
   "id": "05"
   }
   ],
   "key": "IPP Master Key",
   "destination": "6"
   },
   {
   "userId": 8,
   "name": "A-KEYTST-DEVm7",
   "VRKcustomerId": "VHQ-DUKPT-MSK",
   "sourceKeyObject": {
   "keyUsage": "M0",
   "modeOfUse": "C",
   "name": "DEVm7"
   },
   "headers": [
   {
   "content": "n",
   "id": "01"
   },
   {
   "content": "m",
   "id": "04"
   },
   {
   "content": "R1",
   "id": "02"
   },
   {
   "content": "083083",
   "id": "03"
   },
   {
   "content": "7",
   "id": "05"
   }
   ],
   "keyType": "IPP Master Key",
   "destination": "7"
   },
   {
   "customerId": 8,
   "name": "name",
   "uniqueId": "remove",
   "source": {
   "key": "D0",
   "mode": "B",
   "name": "A-KEYTST-PNP-NHMAC"
   },
   "headers": [
   {
   "content": "1",
   "id": "11"
   },
   {
   "content": "ESDFGH_567",
   "id": "10"
   }
   ],
   "key": null,
   "destination": ""
   },
   {},
   {},
   {},
   {},
   {},
   {},
   {},
   ]
2. second object

   [
   {
   "Id": 098,
   "UniqueId": "remove",
   "Destination": "",
   "Key": "",
   "Name": "name",
   "Enable": false,
   "Auto": 0
   },
   {
   "Id": 154,
   "UniqueId": "NEO-TEST",
   "Destination": "",
   "Key": "",
   "Name": "A-KEYTST-PNP-NHMAC",
   "Enable": false,
   "Auto": 0
   },
   ]

expected result.

```
[
    {
        "userId": 8,
        "name": "Adfgh",
        "uniqueId": "rthj",
        "source": {
            "key": "0",
            "mode": "d",
            "name": "tev5"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "content": "b",
                "id": "01"
            },
            {
                "content": "m",
                "id": "04"
            },
            {
                "content": "R1",
                "id": "02"
            },
            {
                "content": "083083",
                "id": "03"
            },
            {
                "content": "5",
                "id": "05"
            }
        ],
        "key": "IPP Master Key",
        "destination": "5"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8,
        "name": "FGHJKNJKN",
        "uniqueId": "etjhjub",
        "source": {
            "key": "M0",
            "mode": "C",
            "name": "DEVm6"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "content": "n",
                "id": "01"
            },
            {
                "content": "m",
                "id": "04"
            },
            {
                "content": "R1",
                "id": "02"
            },
            {
                "content": "083083",
                "id": "03"
            },
            {
                "content": "6",
                "id": "05"
            }
        ],
        "key": "IPP Master Key",
        "destination": "6"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8,
        "name": "A-KEYTST-DEVm7",
        "VRKcustomerId": "VHQ-DUKPT-MSK",
        "sourceKeyObject": {
            "keyUsage": "M0",
            "modeOfUse": "C",
            "name": "DEVm7"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "content": "n",
                "id": "01"
            },
            {
                "content": "m",
                "id": "04"
            },
            {
                "content": "R1",
                "id": "02"
            },
            {
                "content": "083083",
                "id": "03"
            },
            {
                "content": "7",
                "id": "05"
            }
        ],
        "keyType": "IPP Master Key",
        "destination": "7"
    },
]
```

For to compare them, I created a seperated array for to make them similiar to each other. Used filter, map but it wasn't helpful.

I have tried in different ways, and nothing worked. So I don't have the snippet for the code.
Need to compare main object and second object, based on the difference between them have to modify main object.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Unmitigated updated, it will remove the second object in the second array because it has the same uniqueId, name, key, destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function updateMainObject(mainArray: any[], secondArray: any[]) {
    const updatedMainArray = mainArray.filter((mainItem) => {
    return (
      mainItem &&
      ((mainItem.uniqueId && !secondArray.some((secondItem) => mainItem.uniqueId === secondItem.UniqueId)) ||
      (mainItem.userId && !secondArray.some((secondItem) => mainItem.userId === secondItem.Id)))
    );
  });

  return updatedMainArray;
}
```

You can play with it [there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgbRgbxgIgFcIBTJASQBN8AuGADgBoCwBDAWxNoIEFK4A5gAt8zImAQBHQiSrd8SKEIBWoghBCEkwLnTz4A1iQCe8gAxr87EJV0FqYtp3lQSANwCs+GAF8xQklZbFG5sfVAwV0j5ACNLBGo6fDMARm8-XAIIqKh5dnjEgjMAFnTmcPAc+QAlNLEE8wAmMsz8bJJopLN6AGZunoLzAd9yrMqO3KSvesLkr18YAF0xI1Mk8gAFDZgAWVZoMhgAaRNLW2gENigEcHl5jP1iMjk6JhYOO3wAMQBxAAkAFJHAByQOBlkIEmkslmJCgyhUhDiYg0Wh03H0q3kOwsYmstnkAGFLE5PgARACiADV2AA2Fr4AJBMgQUKtdqdFiDLppEbs8acqzcoqlPkVSITGp1AgNLrNMVjCWC-r9YXJYYPRVVJL0mbme5LFandZbXb7VxIY6nMTna5XG5geT0hVEUgUQpvfCk+Q8AC0RwpAE0ACoAZWDvspNIA7JYqdUjsBiFAQJx3fIqX8AIqRgCqRw2EZ2oaOllR2hIJ2MAHkYsoSMBJq1VrmIKwBJ8cZZ8SRq3BW59iY4PvIo+xY3zGYFgqy6GEtZKko69TyWuLtQR8iuRWuF4LamqzPLNW0BU3kr1Vdv1bvT0rz7Hr2YDcsCKtg8YAA6fTbbPYHS0qzOEgLntW4kgnE8k2gVNng9YdnCSP0AxDcNfQ2YENl9YE-h2HghwISEpBkF4CGBClq19YMKXDMtNArDE32NAgyVxTcbE+AAhEkRyQ-0gzDCMMKwnC8OJScmRnNl10XAhpXwWU5N5KCz3kGiyV+P4AH0PFpR8ZVmFILAWV9DGYsBCAAG0sm0QLtVhrnAgg1weVzyjc3APMWABuABYAAoAKAoiVBSAiSh0CwVpSIAcjMABOegYrEXMoRI2Z+GESwyTsy4HIdeRLCApJLGBXj7CQQQVEsCk2BiSy7DgVhLNIMQeEIFNuDMF1SJSDxihStKYXkcjKOo2ixBy0D8qc-AiuYuaxDKxDeH41ChMw7DcPwmq6oa7gmpakg2o6kAur5HygsC-y4EhRsHRgQhP0oBySD2S5a3rRsAAp2FYS4eCQJBWGMOhWDAYxMFfMLwEoQHgdBmBwchxYAEpcACmAsZgELYCel7XEod6wHhkHIr+gGgZBgA6RBLItb7fv+sByFcdh0bQAA+DH-OxmAkDhLQwBgb7Mb5mAKZZtmYAAMhlsW+cZyXWZIdhqaI6EqFlmWYAAQhhsA4ap4xqY0ThGYNygVfZ9BueVtn1aGrW0BdmBLet6nUuImFUfRgAfP2FexpnLg9p53W1vXLdJk2zZIC2G1h62Obt5mw7dZ3Xfdh2qF91Gg9Rvzed8QurqxgWoCFx7nteonmZjoufCu3Hq4Jkg64+usG1gDB8de4nPu777EBQKBmEt0v-JCkAGupyyQAEb6+8Jgeu8bQugA)